# How to resolve 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable' error?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to write unit test cases for a Angular 2 project.
I am using Angular CLI and Webpack.

There are no errors in the console and the application runs fine when I run it.
However, when i run 'karma start', The test cases are not executed and I get the following errors in console:

```
ERROR in /Users/sunil/my-web-app/src/typings.d.ts (2,13): Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'process'.

ERROR in /Users/sunil/my-web-app/src/typings.d.ts (3,13): Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'module'.

ERROR in /users/sunil/my-web-app/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts (48,13): Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'process'.

ERROR in /users/sunil/my-web-app/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts (85,13): Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'module'.
```

I went through some answers about the same error but in different contexts for 3 hours and did not help much. 
Can anybody explain what is the main reason for this error and how to resolve it when I try to run tests?

Comment: First try would be to check typings and node dependencies

Comment: I checked the files in which the errors are present. Both the files have `process` and `module` variables.. Maybe this is causing the error?

Comment: Might be. Try upgrade, downgrade those libs. Don't know better way to check if they meets system